# C - Loop seems to be halved whenever I encounter spaces

Tags: c, loops

I'm in the process of making a program that parses words from a line, adding a word to a tree when it hits an nonalphanumeric character. Everything goes fine when there are no spaces in a line. However, when there are nonalphanumeric characters, the loop in question (beginning at the line commented in the code) halves in size!

Why does the loop halve?

```
Tree addin (char* filee, Tree tree)
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filee, "r");
    char* hold2 = malloc(99);
    int count=-1;
    char* hold;
    while ((hold=getLine(fp))!=NULL)
    {
        count=-1;
        for (i=0; i<strlen(hold); i++) //The loop in question
        {
            count++;
            if ((isalnum(hold[count])==0)&&(hold[count]!='\n'))
            {
                strncpy(hold2, hold, count);
                hold2[count]='\0';
                hold=strdup(&hold[count+1]);
                count=-1;
                tree = insertT(tree, hold2);
            }
        }
        tree = insertT(tree, hold);
    }
    free(hold);
    fclose(fp);
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Modifying a string like that while you're iterating over it is generally considered dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you find a non-alphanumeric character, your program moves `hold` to point to the remainder of your string, but doesn't reset `i`.  That means you continue iterating from the new `hold` pointer, which is partway into the original one, plus whatever `i` happened to be at that time.  Doing so presumably *at least* skips a bunch of characters, and possibly makes you start operating on memory outside of the string, which is *definitely* bad news.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you change the value of `hold` within the loop, since `strlen(hold)` is reevaluated at each iteration.  A solution could be to save the value of `strlen(hold)` before entering the `for` loop.

Comment: That won't fix the problem.